# Google Play Games Plugin for Unity weird authentication

Tags: android, authentication, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using the latest plugin GooglePlayGame services for Unity. After build apk and manual installation on my Android device everything works flawlessly.
(Signing in, leaderboards etc.) The fun fact is I've published my apk as Alpha-Testing in Google Dev Console and then **Social.localUser.Authenticate** method somehow can't return success. While manual installed apk is working as intended but by some miracle when I download app as tester from store, it is not.

I've checked already SHA-1 prints for apk, api, linked app but everything matches. I really don't know why it's working standalone but not through alpha-testing download. 
I would really appreciate any help.

---

**EDIT1** (fixed but new bug appeared)

=========

I figured out how to properly auth a player!

I had to open Project_API and add new one OAUTH2 clientid with SHA-1 fingerprint of [Google Play Dev Console -> **Signing app certificate**]. By default in API exists OAUTH2 clientid that use SHA-1 fingerprint of [Google Play Dev Console -> **Transsmision certificate**]. I'm still not sure if I made it in a proper way.

Assuming: Now I can sign in to Google Play Game Services as a player but right after using method

`PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI(Resources.leaderboard_best_score);`

LeaderboardUI shows up then suddenly quick disappears. No matter if I restart app or sign out then sign in. This bug really pisses me off. Thanks for any help..

Comment: Did you follow the [Testing and Publishing Game Changes](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub) guide and the [Set up alpha/beta tests](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en). I think you need to specify tester emails before you'll get it working.

Comment: Yes, I followed and set right emails. That's why I could test it standalone (connecting to the same game services).